# Rich snippets for xhtml. and how to microdata this data ? (game's data)

Tags: html, xhtml, rich-snippets

Rich snippets it's only for html5 or it's able in xhtml? cuz my website is in xhtml.

More question, how should I show data with rich snippets to:

1. A game's link that includes: name, image, likes, dislikes, category, description, and upload date (example: `http://only4gamer.com/`)
2. A game's page that includes: name, game's content (swf), description, likes, dislikes, category, upload date, game keys, game tags (example: `http://only4gamer.com/games/game/Superbike-X`)

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Can I see a link to your website? Because based on past experience, XHTML websites are usually not actual XHTML. So you'd be good.

Answer (score 0):

In XHTML you can use [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa/) if your primary concern is to pass validation, but in practical terms on the web nothing is really going to be broken by using Microdata in XHTML.

For your data vocabulary I would look at a combination of the [Review](http://www.schema.org/Review) and [Product](http://www.schema.org/Product) schemas.

Comment: Can you give me pelase an example of microdata game's review ?

Comment: @user2461716 There are lots of examples on the pages I linked to.

Comment: Yes i know, thanks for that. But actually I didn't found how to do it for a game's review... Sorry for being annoying buy please if you can help me - thanks very much.

Comment: @user2461716 Why would a review for a game be different from a review for anything else?